# Does std::string::find() use KMP or a suffix tree?

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching, suffix-tree, knuth-morris-pratt

I wonder which algorithm is used for matching a pattern against a string in the standard library. A suffix tree would be the best choice if one has got more search to perform within the same string.

Is that the data structure behind `std::string::find()` or a one-shot algorithm like Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm is used?

Comment: Such information is just an implementation detail. Only the maximum complexity of the functions, are imposed by the C++ standard. There are plenty of open source implementations of C++ compilers, and you can check how it's done there.

Comment: There is an abyssal difference between the KMP or similar and a data structure like suffix tree. It can really completely change the game

Comment: As I already mentioned - only the complexity is imposed on `std` functions, by the C++ standard. Such things as algorithms used is just an implementation detail, and every vendor can implement internal logic however they want.

Comment: From what I've seen, `string::find` is most often implemented as a brute-force search. You might want to consider using `std:search` instead--it supports specifying a Boyer-Moore or Boyer-Moore-Horspool search. Out of the box it doesn't include KMP or suffix tree searching, but it does specify an interface so you could have `std::search` use them as well if you wanted.